# Via a module, how do I get a specific function to fire when I submit a form?

Tags: module, forms

Below are the four required files to install a module that I created. They are all located within the '/third_party/database_add/' folder. **My issue and my question is located after these files**, which I am including to show what I've done so far.

File: database_add_lang.php

Location: /third_party/database_add/language/english/

```
$lang = array(
'my_module_module_name'     => 'Database_add',
'my_module_module_description'  => 'Contains functionality to add a user to the user table',
''=>''
);
```

File: mcp.database_add.php

Location: /third_party/database_add/

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Module_name_mcp {
    }
/* End of file mcp.module_name.php */
/* Location: ./system/expressionengine/third_party/database_add/mcp.database_add.php */
```

File: mod.database_add.php

Location: /third_party/database_add/

```
class Database_add{
    var $return_data = '';

    function register(){
        $username = "john"
        $passhash = "smith"
        $data = array(
            'User_Name'     =>$username,
            'User_Passhash' =>$passhash
        );
        $query = ee()->db->insert('exp_user', $data);
    }

    function form(){
      $return_data = ee()->functions->form_declaration(array(
        'hidden_fields' => array(
          'ACT' => ee()->functions->fetch_action_id('Database_add', 'register'),
        ),
      ));

      $return_data .= ee()->TMPL->tagdata;
      $return_data .= '</form>';
      return $return_data;
    }
}
```

File: upd.database_add.php

Location: /third_party/database_add/

```
class Database_add_upd{
    var $version = '1.0';

    function install(){
        $data = array(
            'module_name'       => 'Database_add',
            'module_version'    => $this->version,
            'has_cp_backend'    => 'n',
            'has_publish_fields'=> 'n'
        );
        ee()->db->insert('modules', $data);

        $data = array(
            'class'     => 'Database_add',
            'method'    => 'add_user'
        );
        ee()->db->insert('actions', $data);
    }

    function uninstall(){
        ee()->load->dbforge();

        ee()->db->select('module_id');
        $query = ee()->db->get_where('modules', array('module_name' => 'Database_add'));

        ee()->db->where('module_id', $query->row('module_id'));
        ee()->db->delete('module_member_groups');

        ee()->db->where('module_name', 'Database_add');
        ee()->db->delete('modules');

        ee()->db->where('class', 'Database_add');
        ee()->db->delete('actions');

        return TRUE;
    }

    function update($current = ''){
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

That is my file structure. I followed [this EllisLab tutorial](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html) to get this far. My front-end form code looks like this:

```
{exp:database_add:form}
    <input class="text_box" type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    <input class="text_box" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Register" />
{/exp:database_add:form}
```

The above form is simplified of course. The form successfully renders as this:

[image]

Now take a look at my register() function. No matter what I enter into the above form, I expect register() to fire, and the username "john" with the passhash "smith" to be entered into the "exp_user" table. That doesn't happen. The table remains empty. All that happens is my blank 'index.php' page loads.

**My question is: How do I get the register() function to fire when I press the Submit button on the form?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with my a specific line of code in my upd.database_add.php file. The original line was

```
'ACT' => ee()->functions->fetch_action_id('Module_name', 'register'),
```

It should be (and currently is corrected to)

```
'ACT' => ee()->functions->fetch_action_id('Database_add', 'register'),
```

I forgot to put the name of my module as an argument in the fetch_action_id() function. It was searching for the action ID of a function called 'register', but it was trying to look in the wrong module 'Module_name', which doesn't even exist. No error message or anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to also add the XID Hash into your form hidden input with the name "XID" as well for it to fire.

I would suspect that's the issue, but can we see what the rendered form in the front end looks like?

Carl

Comment: You can also turn off "Secure Form" to verify that it's an XID issue. 

XID can be done line this: $XID = (isset($_POST['XID']) == TRUE) ? $_POST['XID'] : ''; EE will do the rest for you.

Comment: I just edited my submission with the screenshot of the rendered form. I'll give the XID hidden field and get back to you about the results in a few minutes.

Comment: Okay, I did a quick google fu and added the following line to my form:
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="<?=XID_SECURE_HASH?>" />
I don't know if that's all I had to do, I am brand new to EE. Anyway, still the register() function did not fire.

Edit: In addition, I just checked the page source. <?=XID_SECURE_HASH?> didn't even render to a string, it displays as the literal value of the 'value' attribute.

Comment: Did you disable secure forms as i suggested? It's a quick way to know if this is really a XID issue. (remove the XID field you just added) CP Home > Administration > Security and Session Preferences > Process form data in Secure Mode?

Comment: I suppose it's not an XID issue then. I commented out the hidden field, and disabled secure mode. I refreshed the page and pressed the submit button. Still no record was added to the database.

Comment: I solved it. The issue was a line in my code, see my submitted answer for details. @madebyhippo, It turns out the XID is automatically inserted by EE, likely by the form() function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any docs, but you could look at my Authenticate add-on for a real world example. This form building process has always been a pain for me, so I built Base Form to make life easier. Your forms will inherits loads of default functionality without you having to code it. This library is due for a 2.0 rewrite at some point, and not perfect, but even still I use it all the time with almost all of my add-ons.

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Base-Form